# limit about store message without collapsing GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Google note about GCM "There is a limit on how many messages can be stored without collapsing. That limit is currently 100. If the limit is reached, all stored messages are discarded. Then when the device is back online, it receives a special message indicating that the limit was reached. The application can then handle the situation properly, typically by requesting a full sync."

so how to my application should requesting a full sync?

Answer (score 2):

This is completely up to you since you need to sync with third party server but
not with the GCM server.

You can follow the same procedure that how you would sync your mobile app with your server.